# What's the purpose of writing void method and is usefulness in main method

Tags: methods

when it doesn't return any value, what are it essence?. And most method with void I have seen have println in is block of statements. what println display is it not a value? what determine is usage(void type method)?

Note: I am novice to programming. And all answers I have seen on void type method are about , doesn't return value.

Answer (score 0):

If a function returns `void`, it means any action the function does is through "side-effects".

Side effects are when a function directly changes the state of something external to the function itself.

When you have a function that prints to the screen using `println`, it's modifying the global output stream (which is outside of the function) by inserting into it whatever text you gave it.

Keep in mind though functions can have side effects and return a value at the same time. A `pop` operation usually modifies the stack object by removing an element from it (side effects), then returns whatever object it popped.

Side effects aren't **necessary** in most cases, but they can be useful. In the above `pop` example, if the method didn't modify the stack directly, it would need to return both a new stack with an element removed, and the removed element. Two things are returned at once usually by wrapping them in something like a tuple.

If your code returns everything and relies on side effects as little as possible, it's known as functional code. If you have code that relies on side effects, it's known as imperative code (gross simplification, but it gets the idea accross).